# Retrieve memory consumption of a process

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, autoit, working-set

My AutoIt script automates test cases. I suspect something is leaking memory. It starts at 10 MB, when test cases are over it reaches around 40 MB ([Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) values).

I want my AutoIt script to report memory consumption after each test case. Knowing the difference I probably can locate the cause.

How can I retrieve memory consumption of a process using an AutoIt script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the WorkingSetSize, which is probably not the exact same value like the one listed in your task manager. According to it's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the working set is the amount of memory physically mapped to the process context at a given time.

Here's how to determine it:

```
$wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 0x10
$wbemFlagForwardOnly = 0x20
$colItems = ""
$strComputer = "localhost"
$pid = Run("notepad")

$objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\localhost\root\CIMV2")
$colItems = $objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " & $pid, "WQL", _
                $wbemFlagReturnImmediately + $wbemFlagForwardOnly)

If IsObj($colItems) And $pid <> -1 Then
   For $objItem In $colItems
      ConsoleWrite("WorkingSetSize: " & $objItem.WorkingSetSize & @CRLF)
   Next
Else
   ConsoleWrite("No WMI Objects Found for class 'Win32_Process' with ProcessId = " & $pid & @CRLF)
EndIf
```

You can as well find out any [other value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the `Win32_Process` object with this method.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) , But I could not understand your code. What is ObjGet trying to do, and from where is it trying to get. Also I didnt understand $pid <> -1. Sorry I am new to autoit

Comment: **1.** As said in its documentation, ObjGet "retrieves a reference to a COM object from an existing process or filename." So you get a COM object from the WMI Service. And with it you can use its methods like `ExecQuery` to get the result of a simle SQL Query. **2.** The `$pid <> -1` just checks for a valid PID. When you use the `Run(...)` function you will get a valid PID of the newly created application, but only, when the program could be found. So basically this says: Don't do anything with the COM object when you ain't got a valid PID - else the `$colItems` would be invalid to access.